# d3.js graticule extent not responsive

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to plot a png map file with graticules. The graticule extent should correspond to the width and height of the map file (see end of script). Although the left and upper extent show correctly, the lower and right extent do not correspond to the map dimensions.
I also played around with the extent values in the map function and only the left and upper extent are responsive.
Any suggestions?

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="./js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="./js/topojson.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery3.1.0.min.js"></script>

<style>

.MapPad {
    padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
    }

.graticule {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-opacity: .15;
    }

.graticule.outline {
    stroke: black;
    stroke-opacity: 1;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    stroke-dasharray: initial;
    }

.LonLatLabel {
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 22px;
    dominant-baseline: central;
    text-anchor: middle;


</style>

<body>

  <div id='cont1_1'></div>


  <script charset="utf-8">
  //The function to plot the maps

  function plotMaps (container, width, height, rasterBounds, demFile){

    var projection = d3.geoMercator()
      .scale(1)
      .translate([0, 0]);

    var b = [projection(rasterBounds[0]), projection(rasterBounds[1])],
      s = 1 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / width, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / height),
      t = [(width - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (height - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2]
    //update projection
    projection
      .scale(s)
      .translate(t)

    // geo path generator
    var path = d3.geoPath()
      .projection(projection)

    var map = d3.select(container).append('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .attr('class', 'MapPad');

     //define the data layers before drawing to ensure the order of appearance
    var gratLines = map.append('g');
    var demLayer = map.append('g');
    var samplPointsLayer = map.append('g');
    var outline = map.append('g');

    //make the graticule
    var graticule = d3.geoGraticule().extent([[rasterBounds[0][0], rasterBounds[1][0]], [rasterBounds[0][1], rasterBounds[1][1]]]).step([1, 1]);

    gratLines.append("path")
        .datum(graticule)
        .attr("class", "graticule")
        .attr("d", path);


    // get the coordinates of the line paths and use them as labels 
    map.selectAll('text')
        .data(graticule.lines())
        .enter().append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
            if (d.coordinates[0][0] == d.coordinates[1][0]) {return (d.coordinates[0][0]);}
            else if (d.coordinates[0][1] == d.coordinates[1][1]) {return (d.coordinates[0][1]);}
            })
        .attr("class","LonLatLabel")
        .attr('transform', function(d) { return ('translate(' + projection(d.coordinates[0])[0] + ',' + projection(d.coordinates[1])[1] + ')')
        });

    //outline of the map   
    outline.append("path")
        .datum(graticule.outline)
        .attr("class", "graticule outline")
        .attr("d", path);


    /*var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(["1", "2", "3"])
        .range(["#ffd633", "#aaff00" , "#267300"]);
    */

    demLayer.append('svg:image')
      .attr('xlink:href', demFile)
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

   d3.json('SamplingPoints.json', function(err, data) {
      samplPointsLayer.selectAll('circles')
      .data(data.features)
      .enter().append('circle')
      .attr('r', 5)
      .each(function(d) {
        var lonlat = projection(d.geometry.coordinates);
        d3.select(this)
          .attr('cx', lonlat[0])
          .attr('cy', lonlat[1])
          .style('fill', 'black')
          .style("opacity", .5)
      });
    });

  }

  //calculate the number with which the size of each map should be divided
  var mainWidth = 230

  //Plot the maps in each div
  //Alps
  var widthAlps = 4665;
  var heightAlps = 3589;
  var resCoefAlps = widthAlps/mainWidth
  var rasterBoundsAlps = [[ 5.907077970880465 , 45.29815864865324 ] , [ 11.330836684119511 , 48.15780097787413 ]];

  plotMaps('#cont1_1', widthAlps/resCoefAlps, heightAlps/resCoefAlps, rasterBoundsAlps, 'dem_alps.png');

  </script>

</body>
```

Here's the result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hwhry.png)

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved! The [xmin, ymin], [xmax, ymax] values in the d3.geoGraticule().extent() function should be:

[rasterBounds[0][0], rasterBounds[0][1]], [rasterBounds[1][0], rasterBounds[1][1]]]